# iOS: Saving a date picker's settings

Tags: ios, xcode, date, uidatepicker, picker

I'm very new to memory management, and I have a question regarding saving a date pickers date. This is the code that I use to save inputted text:

```
NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    event1Field.text = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    event2Field.text = [array objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

How would I edit this to save a date pickers date rather than inputted text? And how would I edit the viewDidLoad method as well? I usually just input the data of the picker in there, like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    [datePicker setDate:now animated:YES];
}
```

But I'm not sure how I would go about loading it into it's saved state. Sorry if these are dumb questions, I'm still pretty new and learning as I go.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to persist data is to use `NSUserDefaults` which is provided by the Foundation framework. It's basically just a key value store which allows you to save small amounts of data.

First and foremost, saving data from a date picker looks something akin to this:

```
// NSUserDefaults is a singleton instance and access to the store is provided 
// by the class method, +standardUserDefaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// Let's pull the date out of our picker
NSDate *selectedDate = [self.datePicker date];

// Store the date object into the user defaults. The key argument expects a 
// string and should be unique. I usually prepend any key with the name 
// of the class it's being used in.
// Savvy programmers would pull this string out into a constant so that 
// it could be accessed from other classes if necessary.
[defaults setObject:selectedDate forKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];
```

Now when we want to pull this data back out and populate our date picker, we could do something like the following...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Get the date. We're going to use a little shorthand instead of creating 
    // a variable for the instance of `NSUserDefaults`.
    NSDate *storedDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];

    // Set the date on the date picker. We're passing `NO` to `animated:` 
    // because we're performing this before the view is on screen, but after
    // it has been loaded.
    [self.datePicker setDate:storedDate animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/)'s a good visual tutorial for [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much Mark! One more question though, where should I put the first block of code for the NSUserDefaults, in the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: That depends on the user experience you're trying to achieve. You may have some button in your UI that saves the state. You could perform that in the action that is triggered by the button.